# Modifying PS script for parsing syslog

Tags: regex, powershell

The PS script shown below writes the `hostname, date and Machine Type` to the `SolarWinds.Net log`.  For example, see the entry below:

`ushdc1691: 19087606: Nov 05 13:29:35.131 UTC : %CCM_CALLMANAGER-CALLMANAGER-3-DeviceTransientConnection:`

I would would like to know how to `remove` the text in between the `Machine Type and the Hostname`.

This script creates an event in the SolarWinds log when a syslog message condition triggers the action running this script.
The command executed by the alert trigger is:
`C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe e:\scripts\createsyslogevent.ps1 '${Hostname}' '${Message}'`

```
param
(
[string] $hostname = $(throw "No Hostname supplied"),
    [string] $message = $(throw "No Message supplied")
)

$regex = [regex] '(^%:$)' #THis regex assumes MessageType present in $message
$out = $regex.split($message)
if ($out.length -eq '3')
{
write-host "Has MessageType"
write-host $out[1]
$description = $hostname + ": " + $out[1]
write-eventlog -logname SolarWinds.Net -EntryType Error -source AlertingEngine -eventID 6888 -message "$description"
exit
}

$regex1 = [regex] '(^[A-Z][a-z][a-z] \d{1,2} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d 201[1-3] )' #This regex assumes no  MessageType, Message starts with date/time and year--we need to test for this pattern first
$out1 = $regex1.split($message)
if ($out1.length -eq '3') 
{
write-host "No MessageType, has year in timestamp"
write-host $out1[1]
$description = $hostname + ": " + $out1[1]
write-eventlog -logname SolarWinds.Net -EntryType Error -source AlertingEngine -eventID 6888 -message "$description"
exit
}

$regex2 = [regex] '(^[A-Z][a-z][a-z] \d{1,2} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d )' #This regex assumes no MessageType, Message starts with date/time and there's no year
$out2 = $regex2.split($message)
if ($out2.length -eq '3')
{
write-host "No MessageType, no year in timestamp"
write-host $out2[1]
$description = $hostname + ": " + $out2[1]
write-eventlog -logname SolarWinds.Net -EntryType Error -source AlertingEngine -eventID 6888 -   message "$description"
exit
}
```

`$message = [regex]::Replace($message, '(^.+%.+?: )', "");`

Comment: Please add input and desired output strings. The input sample doesn't contain anything that looks like a hostname.